# Minecraft won't launch: java.lang.NullPointerException: Rendering overlay

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

The game crashed whilst rendering overlay.

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Rendering overlay

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Oops.

Time: 7/10/19 11:05 AM
Description: Rendering overlay

java.lang.NullPointerException: Rendering overlay
    at wm.a(SourceFile:139)
    at duw.a(SourceFile:65)
    at xa.a(SourceFile:159)
    at xl.a(SourceFile:101)
    at cyd$1.a(SourceFile:63)
    at cyd$1.b(SourceFile:55)
    at xj.a(SourceFile:11)
    at xj$$Lambda$1617/1989797386.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1574)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at wm.a(SourceFile:139)
    at duw.a(SourceFile:65)
    at xa.a(SourceFile:159)
    at xl.a(SourceFile:101)
    at cyd$1.a(SourceFile:63)
    at cyd$1.b(SourceFile:55)
    at xj.a(SourceFile:11)
    at xj$$Lambda$1617/1989797386.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1574)

-- Overlay render details --
Details:
    Overlay name: czn
Stacktrace:
    at dko.a(SourceFile:676)
    at cvo.e(SourceFile:954)
    at cvo.b(SourceFile:411)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:154)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.14.3
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1649689408 bytes (1573 MB) / 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    Launched Version: 1.14.3
    LWJGL: 3.2.2 build 10
    OpenGL: GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.5.0 NVIDIA 382.05, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

Comment: Just like the answer say, try reinstall the minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

You might have corrupted files.

You could try to uninstall and reinstall Minecraft.